# Can somone explain this DMARC report? did it fail or pass? why am i getting these if they passed?

Tags: email, dmarc

Can anyone tell me what this means? As far as I can tell they all pass, but I dont know if this is yahoo sending me this or my server telling this passed or what. My server I set up DMARC I think

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<feedback>  
  <report_metadata> 
    <org_name>Yahoo! Inc.</org_name>    
   <email>postmaster@dmarc.yahoo.com</email>    
    <report_id>1607044194.282815</report_id>    
   <date_range> 
    <begin>1606953600</begin>   
     <end>1607039999</end>  
    </date_range>   
  </report_metadata>    
  <policy_published>    
    <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
    <adkim>r</adkim>    
   <aspf>r</aspf>   
   <p>quarantine</p>    
    <pct>100</pct>  
 </policy_published>    
<record>    
  <row> 
  <source_ip>209.85.160.174</source_ip> 
  <count>1</count>  
  <policy_evaluated>    
    <disposition>none</disposition> 
    <dkim>pass</dkim>   
    <spf>pass</spf> 
  </policy_evaluated>   
   </row>   
 <identifiers>  
  <header_from>finelinewow.com</header_from>    
   </identifiers>   
  <auth_results>    
  <dkim>    
    <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
    <result>pass</result>   
  </dkim>   
  <spf> 
    <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
    <result>pass</result>   
  </spf>    
 </auth_results>    
 </record>  
 <record>   
 <row>  
  <source_ip>209.85.219.49</source_ip>  
  <count>1</count>  
  <policy_evaluated>    
    <disposition>none</disposition> 
    <dkim>pass</dkim>   
    <spf>pass</spf> 
  </policy_evaluated>   
  </row>    
  <identifiers> 
    <header_from>finelinewow.com</header_from>  
    </identifiers>  
  <auth_results>    
   <dkim>   
    <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
    <result>pass</result>   
  </dkim>   
  <spf> 
    <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
    <result>pass</result>   
  </spf>    
  </auth_results>   
 </record>  
 <record>   
   <row>    
      <source_ip>209.85.222.174</source_ip> 
     <count>1</count>   
      <policy_evaluated>    
    <disposition>none</disposition> 
    <dkim>pass</dkim>   
       <spf>pass</spf>  
     </policy_evaluated>    
   </row>   
   <identifiers>    
      <header_from>finelinewow.com</header_from>    
    </identifiers>  
    <auth_results>  
      <dkim>    
        <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
        <result>pass</result>   
      </dkim>   
      <spf> 
        <domain>finelinewow.com</domain>    
        <result>pass</result>   
     </spf> 
   </auth_results>  
 </record>  
</feedback>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a DMARC report. Look for the `rua` and `ruf` fields in your DNS entry.

That's essentially just to give you information about the successes and failures of your DMARC policy.

From [RFC 7489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489):

> rua: Addresses to which aggregate feedback is to be sent (comma- separated plain-text list of DMARC URIs; OPTIONAL). A comma or exclamation point that is part of such a DMARC URI MUST be encoded per Section 2.1 of [URI] so as to distinguish it from the list delimiter or an OPTIONAL size limit.

See the [appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#appendix-C) of the RFC for details about the format.

Answer (score 2):

Someone, presumably the person managing your mail, **specifically requested** Yahoo to send *DMARC* aggregate reports to you.

This is purely **opt-in**, if it is not useful to you, consider removing your  address from your published *DMARC* record. Recipients would then stop sending these informational reports while continuing to act on your published policy.

You can achieve that by changing your current record:

> v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;sp=none;adkim=r;aspf=r;pct=100;fo=0;rf=afrf;ri=86400;rua=mailto:jason@finelinewow.com;ruf=mailto:jason@finelinewow.com

to strip all the configuration related to reporting, while keeping the policy in place:

> v=DMARC1;p=quarantine;sp=none;adkim=r;aspf=r;pct=100

Or, **just update the recipient to some other mailbox, one more appropriate for typically not human-consumed mail**, so you can receive & store this information somewhere in case you do want to investigate later.

While this particular report does not indicate any mail received by Yahoo to have violated your published policy, the reports will usually be sent for *any* mail, both passing and failing. It is typical to direct such reports to specialised software (or commercial service provider), only acting on alerts created from aggregated data, rather than reading individual reports.